# How to use bind and unbind function instead of on click function on class using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, bind, unbind

Here, I have a very small module. In which I have a timeline and slideshow.

In my timeline, Everything works fine. But when I going to the slideshow.
It also works fine using on click function on the class name.
But I want to use **bind** and **unbind** function on next and previous button click.
 Here, is my code please review it and help will be appreaciated.

```js
var divSlide = document.querySelectorAll('#slide');
 var myNodeList = divSlide.length;
 let slideNo = 1;
 for(var i = 0; i < myNodeList; i++) {
  var type = divSlide[i].getAttribute("type");
  if (type == "timeline") {
  } else if (type == "slideshow") {
   var timeline = divSlide[i];     
   let sliderData = timeline.getElementsByTagName("section");
   $("[type=slideshow] section").addClass('hide');
   $("[type=slideshow]").each( function(i,ele){
    $(ele).children("section:first").removeClass("hide").addClass('active');
   });
   timeline.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin",'<a class="left uc_prev color_arrow carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>');
   
   timeline.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin','<a class="right uc_next color_arrows  carousel-control" href="#myCarousel"  data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>');
  }
 }

 $(document).on ('click','.uc_prev',function() {
  let select = $(this).parent();
  let totChild = select.children("section");
  for(let i=0;i<totChild.length;i++){
   if(totChild[i].getAttribute('class').indexOf('active')!=-1){
    slideNo=i+1;
   }
  }
  totChild.children('br').remove();
  let current = select.children('.active');
  let prevEl = current.prev('section');
  
  if(slideNo === totChild.length || slideNo > 1){
   select.children(".next").show();
   if(prevEl.length !== 1){
    prevEl = current.prev().prev();
    current.removeClass('active');
    current.addClass('hide');
    prevEl.addClass('active');
    prevEl.addClass('animated');
    prevEl.addClass('fadeInLeft');
    prevEl.removeClass('hide');
   }
  } else {
   select.children(".prev").hide();
  }
 });
 $(document).on ('click','.uc_next',function() {
  let select = $(this).parent();
  let totChild = select.children("section");
  for(let i=0;i<totChild.length;i++){
   if(totChild[i].getAttribute('class').indexOf('active')!=-1){
    slideNo=i+1;
   }
  }
  totChild.children('br').remove();
  let current = select.children('.active');
  let prevEl = current.next('section');
  if(slideNo ===1 || slideNo < totChild.length){ 
   select.children(".prev").show();
   if(prevEl.length !== 1){
    prevEl = current.next().next();
    current.removeClass('active');
    current.addClass('hide');
    prevEl.addClass('animated');
    prevEl.addClass('fadeInRight');
    prevEl.addClass('active');
    prevEl.removeClass('hide');
   }
  } else {
   select.children(".next").hide();
  }
 }); 
 }
```

```css
 
div[type="slideshow"]  {
 height:471px;
 position: relative;
    top: 100px;
}
div[type="slideshow"] > section:not(.hide) {
 margin: auto;
 width: 900px;
 max-height: 265px;
 z-index: 100;
 border-top: 1px solid grey;
 border-left: 4px solid #00BCD4;
 min-height:250px;
 background-color: #b3e5fc2b;
 border-radius: 4px;
 margin-bottom: 55px;
 position: absolute;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 top: 21.4%;
 left: 168px;
 box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 1px;
}

div[type="slideshow"] > section:not(.hide) > header {
 font-weight: 600;
 color: cadetblue;
 transform: translate(93px, 32px);
 font-size: 34px;
 font-family: arial;
 position: relative;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

div[type="slideshow"] > section:not(.hide) > article {
 transform: translate(87px,39px);
 max-width: 800px;
 color: black;
 font-size: 22px;
 font-family: arial;
 position: relative;
 padding: 10px;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

.active{    
 opacity: 1 !important;
}

.hide {
 opacity: 0; 
 min-height: 0 !important; 
 margin: 0 !important;
}
.hide header, .hide article {
 display: none;
}
@keyframes fadein {
 0% { opacity: 0 }
 50% { opacity: 0.5 }
 100% {opacity: 1}
}
br {
 display:none;
}

progress {
 height: 4px;
 top: 46px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: -1px;
 margin-top: -1px;
}
.color_arrow {
 position: relative;
 top: 228px;
 color: #085153;
 left: 93px;
}
.color_arrows {
 position: relative;
 top: 228px;
 color: #085153;
 left: 94% !important;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
 
 div[type="timeline/slideshow"] > section , div[type="timeline"] > section  {
  width: 650px;
 }
 .color_arrow {
  left: -18px;
 }
 div[type="slideshow"] > section:not(.hide) {
  width: 640px;
  left: 14px;
 }
 .color_arrows {
  left: 99% !important;
 }

}
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
 
 div[type="slideshow"] > section  {
  width: 650px;
 }

 div[type="slideshow"] > section:not(.hide) {
  width: 640px;
  left: 18px; 
 }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) and (max-width: 1299px) {
 
 div[type="slideshow"] > section:not(.hide)  {
  width: 845px;
  left: 154px;
 }

} 
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
 
 div[type="slideshow"] > section:not(.hide) {
  width: 698px;
  left: 136px;
 }

}
```

```html
<div type="slideshow" id="slide"><br />
<section><header>Title One</header><br />
<article>Content</article>
</section>
<br />
<section><header>Title Two</header><br />
<article>Content</article>
</section>
<br />
<section><header>Title Three</header><br />
<article>Content</article>
</section>
<br />
<section><header>Title Four</header><br />
<article>Content</article>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: `bind` is deprecated, you should keep with using `on` it also has an opposite method for removing listeners called `off`. Why the requirement of `bind` specifically?

Comment: Yes!! Actually my user want that to use bind unbind function instead of onclick can you see my work. and tell me how can i do this.. please help will br appreaciated

Comment: Anyone please help me.